# How to nest json logs with Fluentd?

Tags: json, parsing, fluentd

I have to transform a log like this:

"key1": "os",

"key2": "linux",

"key3": "redhat"

To:

```
"Data": [{
    "header": [{
        "name": "some-app"
    }],
    "tags": {
      "key1": "os",
      "key2": "linux",
      "key3": "redhat"
 }]
```

I have tried record_transformer but still not able to do it. Please, can anybody help on that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone is looking for same answer, in my case solved using JQ plugin which helped to handle most cases of change on log format:

https://github.com/Gimi/fluent-plugin-jq

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is kubernetes log, you can try this:

```
<filter **.kubernetes.**>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    tags ${{key1: "os", key2: "linux", key3: "redhat", key4: "#{ENV['HOSTNAME']}", key5: record.dig("kubernetes", "namespace_name"))}}
  </record>
  remove_keys $.kubernetes, $.docker
</filter>
```

In your case, you don't need remove_keys, but it can be used to reduce the size of the log.